# Zookeeper client connection pooling

Tags: connection-pooling, apache-zookeeper, apache-curator

Currently I am using a singleton zookeeper client for each request which might not be good performance wise.
I would like to implement zookeeper client connection pooling .Can someone please share examples if there are any

When I use single instance for my application is see below exception in the logs

[http-8082-16-SendThread(10.35.1.205:2181)] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Client session timed out, have not heard from server in 2666ms for sessionid 0x15b157263300002, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
[http-8082-16-EventThread] INFO org.apache.curator.framework.state.ConnectionStateManager - State change: SUSPENDED
[http-8082-16-EventThread] ERROR org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl - Background exception was not retry-able or retry gave up
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Client is not started
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:176)
    at org.apache.curator.CuratorZookeeperClient.getZooKeeper(CuratorZookeeperClient.java:113)
    at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl.performBackgroundOperation(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:821)
    at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl.doSyncForSuspendedConnection(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:696)
    at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl.suspendConnection(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:669)
    at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl.validateConnection(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:616)
    at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl.processEvent(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:861)
    at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl.access$000(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:63)
    at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl$1.process(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:108)
    at org.apache.curator.ConnectionState.process(ConnectionState.java:162)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$EventThread.processEvent(ClientCnxn.java:522)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$EventThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:498)
2017-05-17 15:34:54,377 [Thread-88]  DEBUG - finding config: feed.masterthread.refresh.delaytime.minutes
[http-8082-16-EventThread] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - EventThread shut down
[Curator-ConnectionStateManager-0] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper - Session: 0x15b157263300002 closed

Comment: There is no reason to pool connections. ZooKeeper uses NIO internally and is completely thread safe. 1 ZooKeeper client/instance per application is all you need.

Comment: Thanks Randgalt for your response. While using single instance I see this exception in logs which concerns me                                                                                  [http-8082-16-SendThread(10.35.1.205:2181)] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Client session timed out, have not heard from server in 2666ms for sessionid 0x15b157263300002, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
[http-8082-16-EventThread] INFO org.apache.curator.framework.state.ConnectionStateManager - State change: SUSPENDED

Comment: Well - that's your problem then. Maybe your VM is stuck doing GC, maybe your network is down. It could be a thousand different things. You need to read your logs and figure out what's going on.

Comment: @Randgalt , so each client (Curator framework) creates only one connection to the zk server? and there will be only one session per client, right?

Comment: @niraj yes, that's correct

Comment: @Randgalt could you please also share official documentation link/source of truth for that? thanks for confirming

Comment: @niraj look in ConnectionState.java and HandleHolder.java. Note: I'm the main author of Curator.

Comment: Sorry, God!. thanks :)